# How do you find the integral of $\int \sin^{5/2}x \cos^3x$

Tags: integration

$\int\sin^{5/2}x\cos^3xdx$

I'm confused because I don't know if I should square the entire thing and get

$\int \sin^5x \cos^6xdx$ and then break up $\sin^5x=\sin^4x \sin x$

But does the $dx$ get squared too? How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Squaring it does not help since you don't have any better way of evaluating $\left ( \int \sin(x)^{5/2} \cos(x)^3 dx \right )^2$ anyway. Do you know how to integrate $\int \sin(x)^2 \cos(x)^3 dx$?

Comment: Hint: $\cos^3 x = (\cos x)(1- \sin^2 x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int{\sin^{\frac{5}{2}}(x)\cos^3(x)dx} &= \int{\sin^{\frac{5}{2}}(x)\cos^2(x)\cos(x)dx} = \int{\sin^{\frac{5}{2}}(x)\left(1-\sin^2(x)\right)\cos(x)dx} = \\
&= \left|
\begin{aligned}
u &= \sin(x) \\
du &= \cos(x)dx
\end{aligned}
\right| = \int{u^\frac{5}{2}\left(1-u^2\right)du} = \int{u^\frac{5}{2}du}-\int{u^\frac{9}{2}du}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, you have to apply the formula
$$
\int{u^a}du = \frac{u^{a+1}}{a+1}+C
$$

to both integrals.

Comment: The u-sub block seems weird in the middle, you could just use `I_1\overset{u=\sin(x)}{\vphantom{M}=}I_2` to get $I_1\overset{u=\sin(x)}{\vphantom{M}=}I_2$ I think. (the  vphantom adds more space between the = and the sub).

Answer (score 1):

Recalling that $$\frac{d}{dx}[\sin x] = \cos x,$$ it seems natural to want to choose a substitution of the form $$u = \sin x, \quad du = \cos x \, dx.$$  But you have $\cos^3 x$ in the integrand, not $\cos x$.  What trigonometric identities can you apply to change $\cos^3 x$ into some function of $\sin x$ multiplied by $\cos x$; i.e., how can we write $\sin^{5/2} x \cos^3 x$ in the form $$f(\sin x) \cdot \cos x$$ for some suitable function $f$?